# Single word to describe someone who is overly sensitive

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who is sensitive to the point that other have to tiptoe around her. In other words, someone who can't handle routine jokes, normal criticism, or a comment that can possibly be interpreted in a negative way, even when it wasn't meant like that.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't answer, I guess due to protection and me only having 101 rep. In German, we have a metaphor: 'mimosa' or 'shrinking violet' which is a very sensitive flower, which reacts sensitive on touching. I don't know whether it is used in English too.

Comment: @userunknown We do have the phrase `shrinking violet` in American English. This particular questioner, however, was looking for a single word.

Comment: @dmr you both titled and tagged this as Single word, but you commented on later answers that this was not a requirement.  In the future, please tag and title requests appropriately.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Sure- I will make sure to be more precise in the future.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Someone who is hypersensitive is often said to be *[thin-skinned](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/thin-skinned)*.

Comment: Nice answer, with two good choices for the price of one! :)

Comment: Great answer- thanks! I think I like hypersensitive better; it seems to me to have more of a negative connotation than thin-skinned.

Answer (score 8):

The first word that springs to mind is *[touchy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/touchy)*.

Comment: This is good- but I'm looking to add a sense of vulnerability to the adjective rather than a sense of getting angry.

Comment: @dmr hypersensitive, at least to me, does not really encompass vulnerability.

Answer (score 6):

I like the term "brittle" if you prefer emotional fragility over crabbiness.

If you prefer to infer a certain sour attitude, perhaps "prickly" would fit.

Answer (score 4):

[*Highly strung*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/highly+strung) perhaps?

edit: Admittedly this is not a single word.

Comment: I don't mind that it's two words. However, this adds a sense of the person being tense that I'm not looking for.

Comment: *high-strung* is one word.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of [irascible](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irascible), which conveys the sense of being extremely easy to anger.

Comment: I'm not looking for that sense. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

Consider *[nervous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nervous)* ("Easily agitated or alarmed" and "Apprehensive, anxious, hesitant, worried"), or in the UK, *[nervy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nervy)* ("Feeling nervous, anxious or agitated").  Also *[excitable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/excitable)*, *[edgy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/edgy)* ("nervous, apprehensive"), *[uptight](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uptight)*, *[jumpy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jumpy)*, *[sensitive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sensitive)*, *[fragile](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fragile)*, *[delicate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delicate)*.

Edit: *[Neurotic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neurotic)*, typically negative in connotation, is used informally to mean "overly anxious".

Comment: Fragile is good, but its connotation is more on the positive side while I'm looking for something with a negative subtext.

Comment: @dmr, I've added "Neurotic, typically negative in connotation ..."

Comment: Good suggestion, but I'm looking for something that just means sensitive, not with a nervous side.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the word you are looking for really is ["sensitive":](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sensitive?s=t)

> excessively affected by external agencies or influences.
>   easily pained, annoyed, etc.

Comment: Sensitive is not strong enough for what I want.

Answer (score 1):

What about "susceptible"? I think il fits the sense that you have expressed.

Collins English Dictionary defines "susceptible" as follow: "easily impressed emotionally".

Also, Oxford Advanced Learning's Dictionary defines "susceptible" as follow; "easily influenced by feelings and emotions", ("She was both charming and susceptible.")

Comment: Technically I'm sure you're right, but to me susceptible feels like vulnerable and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Victimizing themselves?
eg. Alice tends to victimize herself.

Or perhaps, to a higher degree, has a persecution complex?

Both are two word phrases and may be more severe than what you intend to use the word for.

Answer (score 0):

In the vernacular, someone who is [hypersensitive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypersensitive) could be called a:

> bitch

Comment: NOT what I was looking for

Comment: [Please don't waste your time being offended](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQ3VcbAfd4w). It's your own choice.

Comment: @zzzBov "..and if you read it and dislike it, you don't have to remain silent about it" ;)

Comment: @dmr, do you believe that my post is ["egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."](http://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-down)? Or do you [find it offensive](http://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/flag-posts)?

Comment: @zzzBov I find it an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect

Comment: @dmr, I did provide what I thought were reasonable indicators that it wouldn't be suitable for all situations (or all readers), in addition to a politically correct alternative. I suppose a hypersensitive reader could come to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: @dmr, What may be dangerously incorrect in one situation is perfect in another. This is **exactly** the word I would use for a hypersensitive person if I were speaking with my friends. If the person was _really_ hypersensitive, I may even add an enhancing expletive.

Comment: @user545424: Point taken. Will refrain from commenting on answers like this in the future.