# An idiom for a very sensitive person

Tags: idioms

Is there an idiom for describing someone who is oversensitive (emotionally, not physically)?

I vaguely remember something along the lines of "he is all exposed nerves".

Comment: See related question: [Single word to describe someone who is overly sensitive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/single-word-to-describe-someone-who-is-overly-sensitive)

Comment: Perhaps [a bundle of nerves](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+a+bundle+of+nerves) was what you heard?

Comment: Or maybe "he is one giant nerve ending"?

Comment: *He is a bitch* can work in some cases.

Comment: You might wish to check out the modern interpretation of the word "snowflake".
For the avoidance of plagiarism and breach of copyright, here is a link to a definition:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snowflake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***to be a bundle of nerves***
***to be wound too tight***  [sic]
***high-strung***
***too tense***

Then there are loads of these types:

***Nervous as a long-tailed cat in a room full of rocking chairs***
***Nervous as a porcupine in a balloon factory***

etc.

Comment: Nervous as a pregnant nun.

Answer (score 2):

You might say that you had to "walk on eggshells" around him, implying that the act of interacting with the person required delicacy and was difficult to accomplish without causing show sort of blow up.

The closest I can come your suggested idiom is "you've hit a raw nerve", which is sometimes said when something has been said to a person who is sensitive about a particular topic.  This does not necessarily carry the implication of sensitivity in general, though.

Comment: Since the OP asked for *an idiom describing a person* I would expect the answer to be something I could insert into the sentence, 'He is <*idiom*>'.  Neither of your answers may be used in that way.

Comment: "He is a person that you need to walk on eggshells around" is a perfectly valid description.

Answer (score 2):

I remember getting together with some former coworkers years ago; we were catching up on old news.  My friend asked:

> *What about Sam?  Is he still a **quivering mass of insecurity**?*

This isn't a common idiom, but it's wonderfully colorful language nonetheless.  There aren't too many utterances that I remember so vividly, word-for-word, even more than 20 years after hearing them.  But sometimes a fresh metaphor beats a well-worn idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Though it somtimes means their feelings are easily read, people who *wear their heart on their sleeve* are said to have their feelings easily hurt.

**Edit**
See [*Because she wears her heart on her sleeve, it's easy to hurt her feelings.*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=sleeve)

Comment: I'd suggest this does not necessarily imply over-sensitivity.  One's emotions can be obvious to others without being excessive.

Comment: -1.  This is incorrect.  As per the reference that you've quoted, it means that they display their feelings openly.  It does not mean that their feelings are easily hurt.

Comment: @DavidWallace There are lots of examples on that page, but did you see the one I am referring to? I copied it into my edit.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I am afraid David Wallace is still right.  The subject of your example has to also be sensitive to emotional manipulation for the sentence to hold true.  To give a similar example, it's possible to say "you can tell from his uniform that he's a police officer", but in actual fact it's not his uniform that makes him an officer, the uniform is merely evidence suggesting that he is.

Answer (score 0):

How about *emotionally delicate* or *emotionally fragile*?

Answer (score 0):

You have to "handle him with kid gloves".  Or her.

Answer (score 0):

It's more a phrase than an idiom, but I think you're looking for "**thin-skinned**"

> (adj.) easily hurt by criticism or easily made unhappy ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thin-skinned))

Comment: I've heard **thick-skinned**, but this is the first time I've heard the opposite...